# About the cardinality of a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to understand the following exercise about set theory:

We have:     $\Omega= \{a,b,c,d\}$

and we are supposed to figure out the cardinality of the following set:

$\textbf{{Y$\subseteq$ $\Omega$ | Y $\cap$ {a,b} = Y \ {c}}}$

According to my tutor the cardinality is $8$, because this set is a power set using the formula of the cardinality for a power set, $2^k$, $2^3$ we get $8$.

I think that I more or less understand what a power set is, in general, and how to compute the cardinality of a given power set.

But I still do not know how I can come to that conclusion in this exercise, or the answer for the cardinality of the set above. Or why the set above has anything to do with a power set.

Comment: There is a much easier way to categorize the valid $\mathbf Y$ than $\textbf{Y $\cap$ {a,b} = Y \ {c}}$.

Comment: Note that $Y \setminus \{ c\} = \{a, b, d\}$. Also note that for any $X$, $X \cap \{a, b\} \subseteq \{a, b\}$. Lastly, note that $\{a, b, d\} \nsubseteq \{a, b\}$.

Comment: An instructive way to work this out is to list all $16$ possible subsets of $\Omega$ (that's the power set of $\Omega$) and count the number that satisfy the requirement. Then you don't have to think about "which formula to use".

Answer (score 1):

The set in question is the set of subsets of $\Omega$ whose intersection with $\{a,b\}$ is the same as removing $c$ from it.

Notice that all subsets of $\{a,b,c\}$ are elements of this set and no other subset can be since that would imply $d\in Y$ but $d\notin Y\cap\{a,b\}$ and $d\in Y\setminus\{c\}$ and these two are equal, so...

Comment: I think you meant "all subsets of $\{a,b,c\}$".

Comment: @AndreasBlass: thank you, typo fixed!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, let's answer this part: "I don't understand how we get the cardinality of a power set".

So, consider a set $\mathrm{A}$ whose cardinality is $n$. Now, the power set $\mathcal{P}(\mathrm{A})$, will contain all sets which have any or no number of elements from $\mathrm{A}$. If you know combinatorics, then the number of ways, is you know,
$$\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n}=2^n$$

Now, as for your question, let the considered set be $\mathrm{A}$.
$$\therefore A = \{\mathrm{Y}\subset\Omega :\ \mathrm{Y}\cap \{a, b\}=\mathrm{Y}\setminus \{c\}\}$$
Now, note that in any case $\mathrm{Y}\cap \{a,b\}\subset \{a,b\}$. Hence, the possible values of $\mathrm{Y}$ as of now are $\emptyset$, $\{a\}$, $\{b\}$ and $\{a,b\}$. Now, for every set $\mathrm{B}$ that does not include $c$, and the same set including $c$, the set $\mathrm{B}\setminus \{c\}$ remains the same. We had got four values for $\mathrm{Y}$, there exist two copies making a valid value of $\mathrm{A}$.

Therefore, the cardinality of $\mathrm{A}$ is $8$, it contains the sets $\emptyset$, $\{c\}$, $\{a\}$, $\{a,c\}$, $\{b\}$, $\{b,c\}$, $\{a,b\}$ and $\{a,b,c\}$.

Hope this helps :)